Names for maps of the form $A \to \mathcal{M}(B)$ between $C^*$-algebras
It is not uncommon in literature to consider a morphism between $C^*$-algebras $A$ and $B$ to be a nondegenerate $*$-homomorphism $\varphi \colon A \to \mathcal{M}(B)$, where $\mathcal{M}(B)$ is the multiplier algebra of $B$. For example, if $f \colon X \to Y$ is a continuous map between locally compact Hausdorff spaces, then the induced precomposition map $a \to a \circ f$ for $a \in C_0(Y)$ is a nondegenerate $*$-homomorphism $C_0(Y) \to C_b(X) \cong \mathcal{M}(C_0(X))$.
Are there any "good" agreed-upon names for morphisms of the form $A \to \mathcal{M}(B)$, and if so what are the references?

I'm not sure I understand? What's wrong with calling them $^*$-homomorphisms?

The distinction is that you still want to consider them morphisms from $A$ to $B$. So like you can say "the category of C*-algebras and $$-homomorphisms" you want to be able to say "the category of C-algebras and <insert_name>" with these other morphisms. It's very clunky to have to instantiate $A$ and $B$ and write nondegenerate $*$-homomorphisms $A \to \mathcal{M}(B)$ every time.

Oh I see. Ah, I think I've seen a name for that.. have you checked the recent paper in acta of Gabe and Szabo? Maybe I saw it there
